# Spring Boot Application startup issues | Endpoints are not loaded

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, startup

I have Spring Boot application with the following package structure

`src/
├── de.mypackages.alivetestservice/
│   ├── adapters/
│   ├── config/
│   ├── domain/
│   ├── exceptions/
│   ├── representations/
│   └── ServiceApplication.java`

- The `adapters/` package represent all elements regarding communication (http & messaging).
- The `config/` package defines configurations for rabbitmq, feign clients, spring security, Sentry, swagger
- The `domain/` package contains the application's business logic
- The `exceptions/` & `representations` packages contains exceptions and Dto definitions.

Startup on a local machine works without any issues. But when the application is build in docker image and is started by our Spinnaker orchestration unit within a Azure Kubernetes cluster the application does not register properly.

**It randomly starts up correctly with this output:**

[https://jsfiddle.net/f63utbqz/](https://jsfiddle.net/f63utbqz/1/)

**And then again... it sometimes starts incorrectly with this output:**

[https://jsfiddle.net/h9vzLdfg/](https://jsfiddle.net/h9vzLdfg/1/)

It seems that there are key components missing on the startup of the application. Because I can not find any log for `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` or `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

My application is started with the following `ServiceApplication.java` file:

```
package de.mypackages.alivetestservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "de.mypackages.alivetestservice")
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AliveTestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Dockerfile configuration looks like this:

`FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]`

**Thread dump of the java application**

```html
2018-12-11 08:24:54
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #25 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ed5800 nid=0x49 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1706377736:1544516413943]" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555ddab8f800 nid=0x24 in Object.wait() [0x00007f68d7ab8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <0x0000000789c1a450> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
 at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 - locked <0x0000000789c1a450> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
 at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"container-0" #23 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd6323800 nid=0x23 waiting on condition [0x00007f68d7bb9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
 at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer$2.run(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:192)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd5f18800 nid=0x22 waiting on condition [0x00007f68d80c4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
 at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1357)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"logback-appender-STASH-logstash-service.logging:5044-4" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd4e10800 nid=0x1e waiting on condition [0x00007f68d96bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c5b8d870> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"logback-appender-STASH-logstash-service.logging:5044-5" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd5cfc000 nid=0x1d runnable [0x00007f68d97bc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:224)
 at net.logstash.logback.appender.AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender$TcpSendingEventHandler$ReaderRunnable.run(AbstractLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java:387)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - <0x00000006c5b4eb70> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"logback-appender-STASH-logstash-service.logging:5044-2" #16 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd4b39000 nid=0x1c waiting on condition [0x00007f68dd327000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c57327e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 at net.logstash.logback.encoder.com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy.waitFor(BlockingWaitStrategy.java:45)
 at net.logstash.logback.encoder.com.lmax.disruptor.ProcessingSequenceBarrier.waitFor(ProcessingSequenceBarrier.java:56)
 at net.logstash.logback.encoder.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:124)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - <0x00000006c5b4e540> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Service Thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3cc6800 nid=0x14 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"C1 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ca8000 nid=0x13 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3c5a000 nid=0x12 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3c4e000 nid=0x11 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3c4c000 nid=0x10 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3c15000 nid=0xf in Object.wait() [0x00007f68ddf2a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <0x00000006c54594d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
 at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 - locked <0x00000006c54594d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
 at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
 at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3c13000 nid=0xe in Object.wait() [0x00007f68de02b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <0x00000006c5459518> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
 - locked <0x00000006c5459518> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
 at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ac2000 nid=0x8 runnable [0x00007f68fa236000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
 - locked <0x000000078bbc3e00> (a java.lang.Object)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
 - locked <0x000000078bbc4688> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
 at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
 at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
 at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
 at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:280)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:421)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:217)
 at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215)
 at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
 at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:319)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:736)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:668)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
 - locked <0x0000000789529ad8> (a org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
 at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:385)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:171)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 - locked <0x00000006c5c05bf8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
 - locked <0x00000006c5ab9360> (a java.lang.Object)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
 at de.myapplication.alivetestservice.AliveTestServiceApplication.main(AliveTestServiceApplication.java:10)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - <0x000000078bb18268> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3c08800 nid=0xd runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ad9000 nid=0x9 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ada800 nid=0xa runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3adc800 nid=0xb runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ade000 nid=0xc runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x0000555dd3ccc000 nid=0x15 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 232
```

Do I need to configure the component scan differently? Or what do I miss?

Comment: When the application starts up correctly it's taking 44 seconds but logging stops in the incorrect case after 7 seconds. It looks like startup has hung in the incorrect case for an unknown reason. Can you capture a thread dump for the incorrect case and share it here?

Comment: Good idea. I'll go ahead and get the thread dump!

Comment: Related?: https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/Hybrid_Cloud_Management:2018.05_Ultimate/Liquibase-database-lock-does-not-get-cleared_23856961

Comment: I also considered liquibase. But the `databasechangeloglock` is cleared and the locked column is `false`... but it's interesting, that the incorrect application start does not contain any liquibase logs at all... that's odd. As if liquibase could be a problematic aspect, which avoids to load the missing application elements.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I tried to do jstack -l 1 (1 is the PID of my app.jar in the loaded docker image)... **but the message is:** `1: Unable to get pid of LinuxThreads manager thread`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That doesn't look wrong, but you could try `kill -3` instead. That should trigger the JVM to log a thread dump to standard out.

Comment: Ok, great idea. But the issue is, that our Spinnaker/Kubernetes combination is restarting the container right away... So it's quite tricky to get to the correct logs. If I kill a correct started application, I get to the logs (containing the thread dump)... but within a conflict application the logs stuck right after the `kill` command and the needed information are not logged... and the container restarts...

Comment: @AndyWilkinson. I edited my question and added the thread dump. Do you see anything useful?

Comment: The main thread is trying to establish a connection to Postgres but, presumably, isn't able to do so. Start up cannot proceed until a connection's been obtained and Liquibase applied any change sets to the database so it gets stuck. I can't tell why a connection to Postgres cannot be established, but that's where I think you should focus your investigation.

Comment: Nice catch, Andy! Thank you very much! We figured out, that we run against the connection limit on our DEV Azure PostgreSQL DB service... 18 services á 5 connections + k8s connections might be over 100. I guess we have to put in some more coins for Azure :D Do you want to create a separate answer so you can get the correct answer / reputation! :)